# Safely remove option missing

Tags: 13.10, usb-drive, eject

I have two USB flash drives. When I connect the first one, the icon in the launcher is that of a USB stick and I get the option "Eject" only.

When I connect the second one, I get a different icon and in the menu there is "Eject" and "Safely remove".

[image: Two different icons for two usb sticks]  Why is Ubuntu seeing the two drives differently?

Comment: Check this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1073597